# geom_line() omits the whole time series when when some quarters are missing

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, missing-data

I am trying to compare fixed asset turnover for 3 different companies. My challenge is that,two of the companies publish annual(A,C) data while the other  publish quarterly data(A), i.e For A and B data is only available at the 4th quarter(end of the year) only. here is the data

```
# A tibble: 30 × 3
   Company time    value
   <chr>   <fct>   <dbl>
 1 A       2019 Q1 NA   
 2 A       2019 Q2 NA   
 3 A       2019 Q3 NA   
 4 A       2019 Q4  7.88
 5 A       2020 Q1 NA   
 6 A       2020 Q2 NA   
 7 A       2020 Q3 NA   
 8 A       2020 Q4  8.52
 9 A       2021 Q1 NA   
10 A       2021 Q2 NA   
11 B       2019 Q1  6.51
12 B       2019 Q2  6.48
13 B       2019 Q3  6.77
14 B       2019 Q4  6.72
15 B       2020 Q1  7.26
16 B       2020 Q2  8.33
17 B       2020 Q3  8.65
18 B       2020 Q4  8.55
19 B       2021 Q1  8.29
20 B       2021 Q2  8.59
21 C       2019 Q1 NA   
22 C       2019 Q2 NA   
23 C       2019 Q3 NA   
24 C       2019 Q4  7.79
25 C       2020 Q1 NA   
26 C       2020 Q2 NA   
27 C       2020 Q3 NA   
28 C       2020 Q4  8.95
29 C       2021 Q1 NA   
30 C       2021 Q2 NA
```

Although on A and C has data on their fourth quarter, geom_line() seems to ignore the whole series.

**The code**

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=`time`,y=value,color=Company,group=Company))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45,hjust=1))
```

[here is graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CbHS.png)

How can i display these other series based on the missing quarters??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least two consecutive points to make a line. You can either drop na and plot with `geom_line`, or just plot with `geom_point`.

Comment: Again many institutions use the most recent statistic until an up-to-date statistic is available. An alternative is to replace the missing quarters with the last available. example 

replace Q1,Q2,Q3 of 2020 with the value of Q4 2019